# iOS8 When using VoiceOver content of the collection view is scrolled to beginning

Tags: ios, voiceover

I have simple collection view created programmatically with build in horizontal layout and 50 items. When I enable VoiceOver to speak content of each cell, scroll position is changed to beginning on first item.

I would like to preserve scroll position. Am I missing something when VoiceOver is enabled?
With voice over disabled it works without issues.

Good to mention it works without issues on iOS7. I am using xcode 6.

Comment: iOS 8 is loaded with VoiceOver bugs. I would assume it is a bug.

Comment: Hope that it is fixed in iOS 8.1. So release of app will wait a bit.

Comment: File a Radar. You can see the same thing happening in photos.

Comment: Already did. Was interested if there is some kind of workaround, but I haven't found any.

Comment: well, have to retest. Apple fixed a lot of accessibility bugs with following updates. Can do tests on iOS11 and 12 on device.